# Laravel Error on Logging

Tags: laravel

I just cloned a project of a colleague of mine.
Configured httpd. But when I go to the landing page I get:

```
FatalThrowableError in ConfigureLogging.php line 59:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging::configureHandler()
```

Laravel is 5.0. Does anyboy had the same issue?

**EDIT**

I solved this problem, because in `config/app.php` the variable 'log' was missing. But now:

```
Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: Dependencies installed with Composer? ;)

Comment: I solved this problem. But now I have another (see the edit)

Comment: although it seems barbaric .. you can always delete the vendor and `composer install` again

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationServiceProvider.php` exists. If not, `rm -r vendor; composer install`.

Second, make sure that your autoload path is OK: In `bootstrap/autoload.php`, ensure that it says `require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` on line 17.

Third, dump all of your config cache: `php artisan cache:clear`.

Fourth, reinitialize the composer autoloader: `composer dumpautoload`.

Report back as to whether the problem is fixed or not.

Comment: the problem is with the app.php. I cloned the repo but it did not contain the config so I downloaded that dir from version 5.4 which is not compatible with 5.0...